# Python: Converting a list of strings into pandas data-frame with two columns a and b, corresponding to odd and even strings respectively

Tags: python, pandas

I have this kind of input as below. It is a list of strings, every odd string is a number starting with MR and every even string is some mixed text. I need to convert this list of strings to a pandas data-frame which strictly has two columns, but because some of the MR numbers are present several times paired with different mixed text counter parts I am getting extra columns everywhere where an MR is repeated, as I am demonstrating below:

```py
list = ['MR4044696:',
 'The GAP Group, GAP – groups, algorithms and programming, version 4.10, Available from http://www.gap-system.org, 2018.',
 'MR2900886:',
 'The GAP Group, $GAP$ groups, algorithms, and programming, version 4.4.12 (2008), http://www.gap-system.org.',
 'MR3169623:',
 'Distler, A., Mitchell, J. D. (2011). Smallsemi - A Library of Small Semigroups. Oct A GAP 4 package [5], Version 0.6.4.',
 'MR3169623:',
 'The GAP Group, (2008). (http://www.gap-system.org). GAP–Groups, Algorithms, and Programming, Version 4.4.12.',
 'MR4180136:',
 'The GAP Group, 2019. GAP – Groups, Algorithms, and Programming, Version 4.10.1; https://www.gap-system.org.',
 'MR11:',
 'GAP group',
 'MR1111111:',
 'Distler, A., Mitchell, J. D. (2011). Smallsemi - A Library of Small Semigroups. Oct A GAP 4 package [5], Version 0.6.4.',
 'MR1111111:',
 'The GAP Group, (2008). (http://www.gap-system.org). GAP–Groups, Algorithms, and Programming, Version 4.4.12.',
 'MR5:',
 'V. A. Artamonov and A. A. Bovdi, Integral gro GAP up rings: Groups of invertible elements and classical $K$-theory, in Algebra, Topology, Geometry, Vol. 27 (Russian), Itogi Nauki i Tekhniki, 232. (Vsesoyuz. Inst. Nauchn. i Tekhn. Inform., Moscow, 1989), pp. 3–43. \nMR1039822',
 'MR5:',
 "V. Bovdi, A. Grishkov and A. Konovalov, Kimmerle @GAP a lapa conjecture for the Held and O'Nan sporadic simple groups, Sci. Math. Jpn. 69(3) (2009) 353–361. \nMR2510100",
 'MR5:',
 'V. Bovdi and A. Konovalov, Integral group ringaper GAP? eg of the McLaughlin simple group, Algebra Discrete Math. 2 (2007) 43–53. \nMR2364062',
 'MR7:',
 'V. A. Artamonov and A. A. Bovdi, Integral gro GAP up rings: Groups of invertible elements and classical $K$-theory, in Algebra, Topology, Geometry, Vol. 27 (Russian), Itogi Nauki i Tekhniki, 232. (Vsesoyuz. Inst. Nauchn. i Tekhn. Inform., Moscow, 1989), pp. 3–43. \nMR1039822',
 'MR7:',
 "V. Bovdi, A. Grishkov and A. Konovalov, Kimmerle @GAP a lapa conjecture for the Held and O'Nan sporadic simple groups, Sci. Math. Jpn. 69(3) (2009) 353–361. \nMR2510100",
 'MR7:',
 'V. Bovdi, E. Jespers and A. Konovalov, Tors gap ion gap GAP gappen units in integral group rings of Janko sgapimple groups, Math. Comp. 80 (2011) 593–615. \nMR2728996',
 'MR7:',
 'V. Bovdi and A. Konovalov, Integral group ringaper GAP? eg of the McLaughlin simple group, Algebra Discrete Math. 2 (2007) 43–53. \nMR2364062',
 'MR9:',
 'The GAP Group, $GAP$ groups, algorithms, and programming, version 4.4.12 (2008), http://www.gap-system.org.']
```

I need to convert to pandas df, having one column for the MR number and another for the rest.
I tried `df = pd.DataFrame(list)` , but because some of the MR numbers are repeating I get extra columns.  I know it is probably a silly question but I cannot solve it, thank you.
[image: output]

I need only two columns and if there is a MR number which repeats I need it in separate rows, like:

```
MR   Rest
111   'asd'
222   'fgh'
333   'fff'
333   'ghj'
444   'yyy'
555   'hjk'
555   'jkl'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(lst)  #here lst is your list...Don't assign anything to list function
c=df.index%2==0  #checking if the index is even bcz the values are in consicutive order 
out=pd.concat((df.loc[c,0].str.strip(':').reset_index(drop=True),df[~c].reset_index()),axis=1).drop('index',1)
#seperating out rows and concat them so that they can become new columns
out.columns=['MR','Rest']  #Finally renaming the columns
```

**OR**

```
df=pd.DataFrame(lst)  #here lst is your list...Don't assign anything to list function
c=df.index%2==0  #checking if the index is even bcz the values are in consicutive order
out=pd.DataFrame([df.loc[c,0].str.strip(':').tolist(),df.loc[~c,0].tolist()],index=['MR','Rest']).T
```

If you print `out` you will get your desired output

If need to remove duplicated values do:

```
out=out.drop_duplicates(subset=['MR'])
#removing duplicated entries on basis of MR column
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd

index = [list[i] for i in range(0, len(list), 2)]
data = [list[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(list), 2)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)\
    .reset_index()\
    .rename(columns={'index': 'MR', 0: 'Rest'})
```

Comment: Hi Rodrigo unfortunately this does not work, it also destroys all repeating MR numbers. I tried to fix it but no good.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code. Now maybe it's more useful